# Twig function: how to return a custom error

Tags: php, symfony, twig, twig-extension

I'm writing a Twig function that creates some links from 1 to 5 and a parameter passed as variable, something like:

```
<a href="myurl.com/criterium=criterium1&value=my_value">text</a>
```

I know I can have only `criterium1`, `criterium2` and `criterium3`, so I have an array with them inside and with `in_array()` I check that the passed critrium is a valid one.

But, if the criterium isn't in the fixed array, I want to return an error and tell the developer which are the allowed criteria.

How can I return this type of error from inside the Twig function?

Something like:

> You passed the criterium "wrong_criterium". Only "criterium1", "criterium2" and "criterium3" are allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna to throw an exception so you can just do it with

```
throw new UndefinedOptionsException();
```

If you wanna just to render some html error so you can do it with :

```
return "<p class='error'>You passed the criterium 'wrong_criterium'. Only 'criterium1', 'criterium2' and 'criterium3' are allowed</p>";
```